# The Weyl dimension formula for fundamental weights

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

The Weyl dimension formula is an equation to calculate the dimension of a simple $\frak{g}$-module $V_{\lambda}$, of highest weight $\lambda$, for $\frak{g}$ a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Explicitly it says
$$
\frac{\prod _{\alpha \in \Delta ^{+}}(\varpi_x +\rho ,\alpha )}{\prod _{\alpha \in \Delta ^{+}}(\rho ,\alpha )},
$$
where $\rho$ is the half-sum of positive roots. Is there a simplification of this formula when $\lambda$ is a fundamental weight? Where can I find some basic explicit determinations of this formula for concrete fundamemtal weights?

Comment: Since this is a straight product formula, in a sense it is already as "simple" as one could possibly hope. However, in the case when $\lambda$ is minuscule (a certain subset of the fundamental weights), there is some other very nice associated combinatorics. See e.g., "On minuscule representations, plane partitions and involutions in complex Lie groups" by Stembridge.

Comment: But if you really want something super "concrete" to focus on: in Type A for the fundamental weights you get the binomial coefficients. It's a good exercise to see why this is (in as many different ways as you can). Hint: the weight spaces are all 1-dimensional in this case...

Comment: The miniscule case looks very interesting! Where precisely is it in the paper? I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment. Well, it depends on what exactly you mean by "it." But e.g. Theorem 3.4 interprets the q-Weyl dimension formula for (multiples of) a minuscule weight as the rank generating function for (multichains in) the corresponding distributive lattice.

Comment: If you're really just looking for a list of dimensions, there is also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuscule_representation.